# Got diamond inheritance working, but Eclipse still complains

Tags: c++, eclipse, diamond-problem

thanks for looking.

I'm going through the software patterns in c++ to become familiar with it, and am having a problem with interface-based programming - namely the diamond problem.

Here's the situation: there's a `Widget` class from which is derived a `Button` class, each with their own interface classes.  The `Widget` class has the `foo` method, and the `Button` class has the `Widget`'s `foo` method and a `bar` method.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IWidget{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~IWidget() {}
};

class IButton : virtual public IWidget{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual ~IButton() {}
};

class CWidget : virtual public IWidget{
public:
    void foo(){ cout << "foo"; }
};

class CButton : public CWidget, public IButton{
public:
    void bar() { cout << "bar"; }
};


int main(){
    CButton button;
    button.foo();
    button.bar();
}
```

So the problem was that CButton was inheriting not only `CWidget`'s `foo`, but also `IButton`'s (which is pure virtual).  But by using virtual inheritance in `IButton` and `CWidget`, this compiles and runs, printing 'foobar' to screen.

The problem though, is that Eclipse is flagging `CButton button` as an error:

```
The type 'CButton' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'IWidget::foo'
```

Which is odd, since everything runs as expected.  Is this a problem with Eclipse's syntax checker?  I know that there are other solutions to this problem, so perhaps Eclipse is trying to tell me that my method is not standard?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

edit: I'm using gcc 4.2 on OSX Lion, and the latest version of Eclipse for c++.

Comment: Do you really need to be able to treat a `CButton` as both `IWidget` and `IButton`?

Comment: I could just define `IButton` to contain a `foo` and a `bar` method.  I'm new to c++ so perhaps this might be the preferred method (it then has the benefit of clarity, since looking at `IButton` tells you all of `CButton`'s functionality)

But then what if there are `foo1`, `foo2`, ..., `foo30` methods in IWidget?  I'd have to copy them all over to IButton, and changing anything in IWidget means manually changing IButton.

Comment: What compiler are you using (note that "eclipse" is not a C++ compiler).  gcc 4.7 builds your example just fine.

Comment: Just for fun, here's a different solution to diamond inheritance [link](http://v2.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/45296/#msg245913).  He uses templates so (using my example) `CButton` inherits `CWidget`, which inherits `IButton`, which inherits `IWidget`.  The problem is to instantiate a widget requires `Widget<IWidget> mywidget;` (ie. you'd have to explicitly put the interface class in the angle-brackets).

Comment: @AndyRoss I'm using gcc 4.2 and it compiles and runs fine for me too.  My problem is Eclipse's syntax checker says there's an error (and underlines `CButton button;` which I'm curious about.  Is it a bug in Eclipse?

Comment: yes, eclipse has all sorts of problems parsing c++ code

Comment: Heh, then ignore my reponse and color me utterly horrified that Eclipse thought it was a good idea to implement a syntax checker distinct from the compiler being used...

Comment: The problem is that gcc cannot be used to provide the information CDT needs in order to do things like intelligent autocompletion. Gcc will simply not provide enough information about the program. And this is, believe it or not, for ideological reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It looks standard to me. My reference is Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language", 3rd edition, 15.2.5.1 on diamond inheritance. He writes, "Two different classes might override different virtual functions from the virtual base. In that way, several derived classes can contribute implementations to the interface presented by a virtual base class." His example has the same structure as yours. It's a big part of what virtual inheritance is for.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but you could try adding a `using CWidget::foo;` to `CButton`.  This is used for resolving ambiguities in multiple inheritance.  See section 15.2.2.